# Kernel restarting when returning multiprocessing shared_memory array

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory, restart

I have the following code, in which I use a multiprocessing approach to change the value of an array in shared memory (using multiprocessing shared_memory).

I noticed that the kernel restarts when I try to return the array in shared memory from the main() function. If I return something else (0, for instance), code runs normally.

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import numpy as np
import concurrent 
from functools import partial

def main():
    
    def add(shared_matrix,index_to_change):
        shared_matrix[index_to_change-1] += 1

    input_list = [1,2,3,4]

    shared_matrix_base = np.array([1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5])
    sharedMemory_matrix = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True,size=shared_matrix_base.nbytes)
    shared_matrix = np.ndarray(shared_matrix_base.shape, dtype=shared_matrix_base.dtype, buffer=sharedMemory_matrix.buf)
    shared_matrix[:] = shared_matrix_base[:] # copy values
    
    print('Shared_matrix',shared_matrix)
    
    add_other_partial = partial(add,shared_matrix)
    
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(add_other_partial,input_list)

    print('Shared Matrix',shared_matrix)

    # return 0 # no problem
    return shared_matrix    
    
output = main()
```

Any idea why this kernel restart happens? I am using Spyder 4 with Python 3.8 in macOS Big Sur.

Comment: A: you don't need shared memory if you're using threads because they all work from the same memory space. B: the shared memory object (`sharedMemory_matrix`) can get garbage collected too soon in some circumstances, and then accessing the numpy array bound to it will cause a segfault. IPython just sees that the kernel aquit abruptly, and tries to re-start. Running from a terminal or command prompt will probably give you the segfault error message (or it might not depending on os/python/shell env.)

Comment: If you intend on swapping `ThreadPoolExecutor` for `ProcessPoolExecutor`, it may be worth fixing the shared memory thing, and [I've answered a number of questions in the past about the topic you might want to browse through](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3220135+shared_memory). Otherwise, just make the array a global variable. In general when working with GUI's or multiprocessing, I usually find IPython gets in the way more than it helps compared to normal python.